# Cannot trigger "Migrate to JUnit 5" dialog in IntelliJ 2017.3.3

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit5

[image: How the dialog should look]

This [blog post](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/11/intellij-idea-2017-3-junit-support/) says that once junit 5 is on the classpath, one can hover over a JUnit 4 test name and a popup for "Migrate to JUnit 5" will appear. I've added the `junit-jupiter-api` dependency (version `5.0.3`) to the pom and no such option is available.

What am I missing?

Comment: The blog states "You need to have junit 5 on the classpath" so it's not explicit about what dependencies are required however the `api` module on its own might not tick this box: "junit 5 on the classpath". Perhaps you need both `junit-jupiter-api` **and** `junit-jupiter-engine` on the classpath?

Comment: The blog post you gave, never states something along the lines: `once junit 5 is on the classpath, one can hover over a JUnit 4 test name and a popup for "Migrate to JUnit 5" will appear` itself. This is only mentioned in a comment. Did you only add the dpenedency to the pom, or did you also update your dependencies?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer it's mentioned in a comment by an IntelliJ dev. Hopefully a trustworthy source. I added the dep and updated dependencies.

Answer (score 11):

I guess this feature is disabled by default now. Maybe it's a bug related to switching. But you can enable this inspection manually.

Try right clicking on the name of the test -> Analyze|Run inspection by name -> **JUnit 4 test can be JUnit 5 inspection**

After that apply the quick fix **Migrate to JUnit 5** and press **Enable inspection**.

[image]

This migration works for me.

[image]

After switching on you can see the inspection's tooltip:
[image]

For this inspection you need:

- JDK8;
- "org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions" class in your classpath;

You need to add the dependency junit-jupiter-api:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>${junit-jupiter-engine.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This is the information from Idea sources:

```
@Override
  public boolean shouldInspect(PsiFile file) {
    if (!JavaVersionService.getInstance().isAtLeast(file, JavaSdkVersion.JDK_1_8)) return false;
    if (JavaPsiFacade.getInstance(file.getProject()).findClass(JUnitCommonClassNames.ORG_JUNIT_JUPITER_API_ASSERTIONS, file.getResolveScope()) == null) {
      return false;
    }
    return super.shouldInspect(file);
  }
```

Comment: One can also enabled the Java | JUnit issues | **JUnit 4 test can be JUnit 5** inspection in [Inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/inspections.html) settings.

Comment: @Andrey This *was* true, however, now the "Inspection" doesn't exist anymore. If you run "Code | Analyze Code | Run Inspection by Name..." you can still select it. It's now categorized under "JVM languages" -- in IntelliJ 2021.3.1. Why? No idea.